Connection between Weyl groups of $ E_6 , E_7 , E_8 $ and the finite orthogonal groups over $ \mathbb{F}_2 $
The Weyl group of $ E_6 $ is the almost simple group $ GO_6^{-}(2) $.
The Weyl group of $ E_7 $ is the product of simple groups $ GO_7(2) \times 2 $.
The Weyl group of $ E_8 $ is the almost quasisimple group $ 2 \cdot GO_8^+(2) $.
Note that $ GO_7(2) $ is simple because $ 7 $ is odd. On the other hand, $ GO_6^{-}(2) $ and $ GO_8^+(2) $ are almost simple groups generated by the corresponding simple orthogonal group, which sits inside as an index $ 2 $ normal subgroup, and an order $ 2 $ outer automorphism of that simple orthogonal group.
In the $ E_6 $ case it can be said more specifically that the Weyl group $ GO_6^{-}(2) $ is exactly the full automorphism group of the corresponding simple orthogonal group (the unique simple group of order $ 25920 $) and since there is only a single order $ 2 $ outer automorphism the group is the unique almost simple group of order $ 51840 $.
Bottom line, for $ n=6,7,8 $ the Weyl group of $ E_n $ has a very close relationship with, with a slight abuse of notation, $ GO_n(2) $. Why is that? Is there some conceptual reason that the Weyl group of $ E_n $ would be related to $ GO_n(2) $? It seems hard to imagine that this happening in all three cases is just a coincidence of low dimensions?

Can whoever is downvoting explain what they thought is unclear or insufficiently well explained about the post?

Here are some ideas for seeing the relation with the orthogonal groups over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
Let $\Phi$ be a root system of rank $d$. Then $L = \mathbb{Z}\Phi$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-lattice of rank $d$, and the Weyl group $W$ acts on $L$.
Therefore $W$ also acts on $L/2L$, which is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space of dimension $d$.
So this gives you a representation $\rho: W \rightarrow GL(d,2)$.
Assuming the root system $\Phi$ is simply laced, you can define a non-degenerate $W$-invariant quadratic form on $L/2L$, so the image of $\rho$ is contained in an orthogonal group. (Idea: take $b(-,-)$ to be a $W$-invariant symmetric bilinear form on the Euclidean space where $\Phi$ lives. By a suitable choice of $b$, you get a quadratic form $q: L \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by $q(v) = \frac{1}{2}(v,v)$, which then gives you the desired quadratic form $\tilde{q}: L/2L \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$.)
The following hold:
For $\Phi = E_6$, the representation $\rho$ is faithful with image $O_6^{-}(2)$. So $W(E_6) \cong O_6^{-}(2)$.
For $\Phi = E_7$, you have $\operatorname{Ker} \rho = Z(W)$ cyclic of order $2$, and $\rho$ has image $O_7(2) \cong Sp(6,2)$. (Here the generator of $Z(W)$ acts as $-1$ on $\Phi$, hence trivially on $L/2L$.) So $W(E_7) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times O_7(2)$.
For $\Phi = E_8$, you have $\operatorname{Ker} \rho = Z(W)$ cyclic of order $2$, and $\rho$ has image $O_8^{+}(2)$.

I see, https://mathoverflow.net/q/230120/148524 seems related. Is there some reason we expect the mod $ q $ reduction to admit a nice non-degenerate W-invariant quadratic form on $ L/qL $ for the specific case of $ q=2 $? Why not, for example, do it for $ q=3 $? Or does reduction mod any $ q $ work, but the representation $ \rho: W \to GL(d,q) $ is only surjective onto the orthogonal group when $ q=2 $?

@IanGershonTeixeira: I guess it should work for $L/pL$ for every prime $p$ with the same approach. But then the orthogonal group has larger order, so the image of $W$ is not the full orthogonal group.

Do you think this same trick could be used to relate the Weyl group of $ F_4 $ to something roughly like $ O_4(2) $?

It seems you can get $W(F_4) \cong O_4^{+}(3)$ with this construction. Actually for the quadratic form $q$ on $L/2L$ to be nondegenerate, maybe we need to assume that the root system is simply laced. So for $W(F_4)$, you don't actually get a map into $Sp(4,2)$ in this way.

Interesting. I can certainly imagine $W(A_n)=S_{n+1} $ embedding into $ O_n(2) $ through the standard degree $ n $ irrep (i.e. the degree $ n $ subrep of the natural degree $ n+1 $ permutation representation). The last simply laced type is $ D_n $, but I usually think of $ W(D_n) $ as the subgroup of $ n \times n $ signed permutations with an even number of sign changes, so lots of $ \pm 1 $, so that seems more natural to define over $ \mathbb{F}_3 $ than $ \mathbb{F}_2 $. Does $ W(D_n) $ really go in $ O_n(2) $ in a natural way? That seems surprising.

Also you wrote $ Sp(4,2) $ in your most recent comment, which is isomorphic to $ S_6 $, did you mean to write some orthogonal group like $ O(4,2) $ instead? Otherwise I'm not really following.

@IanGershonTeixeira: I wrote $Sp(4,2)$ since $O^{\pm}(4,2) < Sp(4,2)$. Now I'm not sure about $W(D_n)$ anymore, I'll have to check the details to see how this works out. But for $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$ it does work.
